# Cannot compile c program with -m32 flag and -ledit

Tags: c, gcc, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to compile a c program to 32 bit from a 64 bit linux gcc.
This is the full c code:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/h4r1337/wentlisp/main/main.c

But when I tried compiling it with `-m32` flag this error shows up.

```
$ cc -m32 -std=c99 main.c -o main.out ledit

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.so when searching for -ledit
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.a when searching for -ledit
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ledit: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.so when searching for -ledit
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I already installed `gcc-mltilib` and `g++-multilib`

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

I am a beginner c programmer and trying out and learning new things. I couldn't find anything useful from google or I am not that good at googling specific errors. Can anyone please help...

Comment: To build a 32-bit program, you also need 32-bit versions of all the libraries it links with, such as `libedit`.  You'll need to install those.  I'm not sure, but `sudo apt-get install libedit2:i386` may work.  If not, specify what distribution you are using.

Comment: @NateEldredge I tried installing that but the error is still there. also tried `libedit-dev:i386`
but showing this error:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libedit-dev:i386 : Depends: libncurses-dev:i386 but it is not installable or
                             libtinfo-dev:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: Is this a linker issue? like I have to link to the 32 bit version of libedit?

Comment: Yes, you have to link to the 32-bit version of libedit.  The question is how to install that, which I am not sure of.